# How to restrict child views to inherit parent view's animation

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout, layout-animation

I have a LinearLayout that have a ListView and a LinearLayout init.
Based on some condition I just change the visibility of the parent linear layout.
Whenever I set visibility as Visible to the parent,I set bottom-up animation programmatically as follows.

```
parentLinearLayout.setLayoutAnimation((AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.layout_anim_bottom_up)));
```

The animation is happening for me.

But I want only the parent layout to get bottom up animation but all child views inside the parent layout reflecting the bottom up animation. So the overall transition looks messy.

Is there is any way around to restrict child views from reflecting parent's animation ?